# findALL is not working

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

This is how I am trying to get all links:

```
soup.find("div", attrs={"class": "vl-article-title"}).find("h3").find("span").find("a")
```

This finds just first one, but as I said I need all of them.

Why this isn't working:

```
soup.findAll("div", attrs={"class": "vl-article-title"}).find("h3").find("span").find("a")
```

?

I am getting an error:

```
'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'find'
```

Comment: Because `ResultSet` has no attribute `find`. You need to iterate over it.

Comment: For the record: `findAll` is *working just fine*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for i in soup.findAll(...):
    i.find("h3").find("span").find("a")
```

Answer (score 2):

`findAll` returns a `ResultSet` which has no method `find`. You can treat the `ResultSet` as a kind of list, so you can iterate over it as pacholik suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You will not get any result with findAll in this case because

```
findAll()
```

returns a list of bs4 objects. What you need to do is iterate over each of those objects and run

```
find()
```

on them. You can do something similar to this:

```
list_of_divs = soup.findAll("div", attrs = {"class" : "vl-article-title"})
#now iterate over every div
for i in list_of_divs:
    link = i.find("h3").find("span").find("a")
    print link.getText() + " : " + link["href"]
```